# How to replace columns (matching pattern) using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to use awk to edit files but I cant manage to do it without creating intermediate files.

Basicaly I want to search using column 1 in file2 and file3 and so on, and replace the 2nd column for matching 1st column lines. (note that file2 and file3 may contain other stuff)

I have

File1.txt

```
aaa 111
aaa 222 
bbb 333
bbb 444
```

File2.txt

```
zzz zzz
aaa 999
zzz zzz
aaa 888
```

File3.txt

```
bbb 000
bbb 001
yyy yyy
yyy yyy
```

Desired output

```
aaa 999
aaa 888 
bbb 000
bbb 001
```

Comment: Often you can avoid intermediate files using something like `<(cat File2.txt File3.txt)`. The `awk` is better here then something as ugly as `grep -Ff  <(sed 's/\([^ ]*\) .*/^\1/' File1.txt) <(cat File2.txt File3.txt)` (just for showing how to avoid intermediate files).

Answer (score 2):

this does what you specified but I guess there are many edge cases not covered.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file{1..3}

aaa 999
aaa 888
bbb 000
bbb 001
```